# Relationship between git branches and a release

Tags: git, version-control, commit, git-branch, git-commit

I've used `git` for sometime now, but it isn't clear how git `commit`s relate to `releases` which relate to the `master` branch.

My understanding now is `master` branch is like any other branch in git. It is just created with `git init` upon initially making a git repository.

Thus, can someone explain the relationship between `git branches` to a `release`?

Is it a `1 or M:1` relationship? (e.g. 1 or many branches are in a release) ?

Also, within a git `branch` how are the individual changes tracked? e.g. in one branch, I change the letter `B` in `filex.py` to `C` and commit it to a branch?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git does not impose any such requirements or workflow on you.

A popular approach is that `master` always represents the latest production release, and is only merged to immediately prior to a release, so that this is the case.

Another tactic is to have a `release` branch that does the same as the above.

Finally, git tags could be used, usually in conjunction with SemVer or some other versioning approach. This makes sense when numerous different versions are in production at once and you need to differentiate between them, or need to produce and associate release notes with a particular tag.

Similarly to the above, you may also end up with different release branches for different versions. This is useful if you expect separate development to continue on those branches.

Which branches go into a release depend on your workflow.

If you have a bunch of developers working on different features and bugfixes, you may end up with a bunch of branches all being merged together prior to a release. For example:-

- feature/abc
- feature/xyz
- bugfix/1234
- bugfix/9999

Depending on your QA approach and workflow, they'd be tested and merged or merged and tested, into a release preparation branch, or straight into master and released. There really are a lot of approaches you can take, which depend on the size and nature of your team, how flexible you need to be, etc.

Comment: I guess this can be boiled down to `it depends` haha. But I think this gives a good overview of what tends to happen @bcmcfc